# Why does the image in my loaded page quickly appear then disappear?

Tags: css, meteor, iron-router, meteor-helper

When my page loads, an image in the header quickly appears then magically disappears within a couple of nano-seconds. Sometimes, however the page loads correctly, meaning the image in the header actually remains visible. 
I cant figure out why this randomly happens.

Ideally, the page along with the image is supposed to load and remain visible.

I have a included the related helper, events, CSS and HTML snippets to aid in understanding whats going on.

Find below my template:

```
<template name="merchantChat">  
{{#each chatMessages}}
    <img class = "img-responsive img-rounded blur" src="{{this.photo.url}}" alt="thumbnail" >
{{/each}}
</template>
```

Find below my CSS:

```
img.blur{
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
   margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0px;
    clip: rect(5px,640px,50px,5px);
    zoom:190%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(1.3px);
    filter: blur(0.9px);
}
```

and my helper as a Router function:

```
Router.route('/merchantChat/:_id', {
template: 'merchantChat',
data:{ 

    chatMessages: function()
            {

            var selected = Router.current().params._id;
            return buyList.find({ _id: selected}).fetch();               
            },
    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `this.photo.url` exists?

Comment: I assume you tried changing the z-index? Also, without seeing the other classes, this seems to be a css problem. I would strip away all the extras (e.g. zoom, filter, clip etc.) and try adding them back one by one.

Comment: @MaximPokrovskii yes it exists. I can tell because sometimes when the page loads it appears correctly displays the image, but for the most part it appears for a few like half a second, then disappears.  :-(

Comment: @Daltron Yes I tried changing the z-index. Its currently at 10, with no positive effect. Also as you suggested, tried removing the extras such as: zoom, filter, clip e.t.c. still made no difference. I then tried omitting the "img-rounded and blur" class names from the template leaving only the "img-responsive" and still, this made NO difference. I am beginning to think this is a cursor issue... :-(

Comment: @Daltron Further, what is also strange is that when I look for the `img` element, which holds the `img-responsive img-rounded blur` classes via the chrome Elements tab. Its not visible. Its like they never existed.

Comment: @SirBT Hmm, have you tried just logging your `chatMessages`  function and make sure it is giving you data? Also checking that you are getting the params ID? If all that checks out, then you have a css problem.

Comment: @Daltron thanks. I managed to resolve the issue after hours of pounding my head on the wall, you might want to check out how I resolved the issue.

Comment: @SirBT Great job on solving it. I wish I could have helped more!

Answer (score 1):

The issue had nothing to do with the CSS as we earlier thought, but had to do with the approach I was using to access the image in the object.

It seems like the reason why the image would blink is because the

```
{{#each chatMessages}}
    <img class = "img-responsive img-rounded blur" src="{{this.photo.url}}" alt="thumbnail" >
{{/each}}
```

would iterate through the cursor, the first time displaying the image, then erasing the image in preparation to display the second image, which would never come...

To correct this issue, I looked back at how I was accessing the image in the object:

```
Router.route('/merchantChat/:_id', {
template: 'merchantChat',
data:{ 

       chatMessages: function()
        {
           var selected = Router.current().params._id;
           return buyList.find({ _id: selected}).fetch();               
        },
}
});
```

and changed this to:

```
Router.route('/merchantChat/:_id', {
template: 'merchantChat',
data:{ 

       chatMessages: function()
       {    
        var selected = Router.current().params._id;
        return buyList.find({ _id: selectedBargain }).fetch().map(function(image) { return image.photo.url(); });
        },
    }
});
```

Leaving the CSS file as it is, I changed the template from:

```
<template name="merchantChat">  {{#each chatMessages}}
<img class = "img-responsive img-rounded blur" src={{this.photo.url}}"alt="thumbnail" >
{{/each}}
</template>
```

To:

```
<template name="merchantChat">  
{{#if chatMessages}}
<img class = "img-responsive img-rounded blur" src="{{chatMessages}}" alt="thumbnail" >
{{/if}}
</template>
```

Now the image always displays on page load :-)